# Why do we need multiple node modules folders inside each project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm new to JS development and was wondering given that the size of node modules is an issue of concern where one has to even go on deleting the folder when many projects pile up and is not used, why can't we have a global node modules folder, like m2 for maven and then reference it in our projects?

Why do we need multiple node modules folders inside each project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* install packages globally and use them [with the -g flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally) when using `npm install`.

But this isn't done often, and often isn't recommended, because the same package can have many, many different versions. SomeLibrary version 5.6.1 can be significantly different from SomeLibrary version 5.7.1. If you have multiple projects, they'll very often have different dependencies, and different dependency versions. If you try to source them all from the *same* global install, you'll usually run into problems very quickly. Having a separate `node_modules` folder for each project solves this problem for you; often, package versioning for each project you have will "just work" without any extra configuration.

There are also managers like [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/features/offline-cache) which can cache package downloads, so you don't re-download huge numbers of duplicate megabytes over multiple projects

Comment: I've been using Maven and Gradle for several years, I haven't encountered any of the issues you are referring here.

Comment: The build system should be "clever" enough to point to whatever dependencies already exist in the global repository of your machine. There is a new package manager called `pnpm` that is aiming to solve those issues. I've used it on my machine and so far it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Variety of reasons. Just FYI, you can install npm packages globally using the -g flag when installing.

Here's some reasons:

1. Different project may require different versions of a package.
2. A single machine can consist of multiple different environment, i.e
   containers or virtual machines.
3. Sharing code between projects/environments introduces potential security risks.
4. For the above reasons, and others, you might not actually want a projects
   packages to leave the scope of that project.

Answer (score 0):

since java script is not compiled, we will need to have all the plugins in each deployment verses maven is compiled so we can compile it to machine code with the plugin globally installed

Comment: To have a node modules in each project is totally optional. You can install package globally and use in you project. But the problem is when packages got updated code may break. So it is always preferable to have node modules specific to each project.